# Memory allocation after assigning a value in Java

Tags: java, memory-management, declaration, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm wondering how the memory is allocated in a simple cases regarding variable declaration and assigning value. Let's say we have following:

int a;

As far as I know 4 bytes are allocated once we daclare int a; . But, how memory works when we assign a value to a? I guess there is a difference in terms of memory between following:

a = 1;
a = 1000000;

So, actually, the question is how assigning a value affects the memory.

Comment: "*So, actually, the question is how assigning a value affects the memory.*" - For `int`s (or really any of the eight primitives), It does not. Both values are 32-bit integers, and therefore consume the exact same amount of memory.

Comment: Interesting, so that is why the declaration is important in terms of memory allocated. I guess the same is for other primitive types? I guess for String the story is different. Thanks for the answer.  @Turing85

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are allocated by the compiler on the call stack of the method.

```
void f(int a, String b) {
    String d = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        int c;
        c = a*i;
        d = d + b;
    }
}
```

Stack:

```
Compiler stores frame size of `f(int, String)`: 28
fp[0] int a
fp[4] String b
fp[12] String d
fp[16] int c
fp[24] int i
fp[28]
```

On every call something like this happens:

```
checkStackCanReserveFrameWithSize(28); // can throw OutOfMemoryException
```

Copied is

- the value of a primitive type, or
- the object reference of an Object.

So no allocation on assignment.

Above `d + b` does an allocation, `String.concat(String)`.

- Field variables are allocated as part of the object allocation.
- Static field variables (global fields) are allocated as class initialisation.

Comment: The first entry for a non-`static` method will be `this`. Besides that, `i` occurs first in the example source code. In principle, the compiler could assign the locations for `i` and `c` however it likes, but for simplicity, I'd use the source code appearance order (as also happens in practice). It's worth noting that the *memory* for the stack is usually allocated when the thread is created.

Comment: @Holger Thanks, useful info, I simplified. Ther